# How to handle pathfinding and path following with sprites the same size as the grid?

Tags: c++, sprites, tiles, sdl

The game I am working on is currently using 32X32 collision boxes. I have implemented a working AI (A* - path finding method) which is based on the Grid Size.

Lets say that I use that 16x16 grid , then if I try to implement a sprite to the AI, bigger than 16x16 the path finding will work but part of the sprite will go thru walls, because the AI follows the path generated by A* for a 16x16 grid. Same rules applies if the grid is even smaller  (8x8 for example). Is there a way to actually fix that problem. I do not know if that is possible, but if I could make the AI to include not 1 but lets say 4*(8x8)boxes then I will have a one Big 16x16 square and I can use a 16x16 sprite picture(or bigger where the same rules apply). But then the A* method should be tweaked.

The main idea is that I will create a Map in Tiled Editor with 16x16 grid , and then add collision 16x16 boxes (manually wherever I need them to be) which will be fed to an array with certain index numbers for each type of collision box (0,1,2 etc).So the bottom line is that I can not use sprites bigger than the collision box (or smaller will cause weird spaces). Am I missing something , or there are other ways of doing that ?

PS: also forgot to mention that if I make the collision boxes equal to the sprite size this won't work in the map, cause the collision wont be smooth or accurate enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path you find with A* and the path a unit travels do not have to be exactly the same path.

You can use methods like [steering](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49497/following-a-path-in-a-smooth-fashion) to follow paths found by A*, while avoiding the corners of your obstacles. Or you can [change the input to your A*](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/94148/pathfinding-tile-based-navigation-mesh/94151#94151) to allow it to find whatever kind of path you like (which can be followed directly). And you can find [paths for units of whatever size](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28222/pathfinding-for-units-of-variable-size) you need.

You can use sprites of whatever size you like, as long as the steering algorithms know about the size and as long as A* knows about their size.