# How can I get a straight path using A*?

Tags: java, libgdx, algorithm, path-finding

How to change A* work so that the path is more like a straight Euclidean distance? I read that you need to break some nodes, but how to implement this?

I need heuristic like this:

[image: example]

Is such a heuristic possible taking into account some obstacles on the map?

Comment: Do you have an image of what you try to get? Also, what do you have so far?

Comment: Yes, there's a couple of different ways I know of to address this problem, but the solutions depend on the situation. Please edit your post to include more details.

Comment: I edit the post. Do you know how to control algoritm behaviour?

Comment: That only illustrates what you want to happen in the easiest possible situation (no obstacles). It would be helpful to see the existing & expected behaviors with at least one obstacle between the start and the destination.

Comment: Does [this question & answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/26545/33287) address your situation? If not, how does it differ?

Comment: On my phone so can't add links, but generally you either use a nav-mesh with A*, use A* plus path smoothing, or use an algorithm that generates smooth paths like Theta*